# Repeat formula every time a criteria is met in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to create a VBA macro that runs everytime a word is found in specific cells and does the following:

- Retrieve values from 1 row below in two cells.
- Remove formulas and leave info as values.

Starting on row 37, there are segments where specific KPIs are asked in order to track them. Right now, the row "Target" is formulated but what I want to do is to replace the current following with another to get the information from the row below (the one from the row called "Real") in P01 and P02 (columns H and I). The rest (columns J to AA), I just want to leave whatever there is there as values.

So, the idea is that in every row where there's the word "target" on column F, to run the macro in the proper range (from row 37 to 576).

I've managed to do it but selecting the range manually.

```
Range("H570").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(R[1]C,""-"")"
Range("H570").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("I570").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("I573").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("J570:AA570").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Is it possible?
I leave a screenshot and the file for you to help.

**Thank you so much in advance!**

[image: Screenshot]

[Access to file](https://mega.nz/#!Th83Ba6L!arHbEta8Vd5GlRaAKvmdzUyGEdGKBGGau7eY4bhW7W4)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking. I suggest in any case you read up on how to avoid select/activate in VBA.

Comment: The idea is to repeat a certain formula either for several times in a loop or every time a word is found (which in this case, is "Target").